# Верстка Android

Tags: android, вёрстка

Есть MapView, который занимает большую часть экрана и Spinner, который располагается под MapView, и занимает столько место, чтоб хватило для текста в нем(по высоте).Как правильно сверстать данный макет?

[image]

До этого делал так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <org.osmdroid.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mapview" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/locationButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/bus_routes_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Загвоздка в том, что когда я поменял тему в приложении, то вся верстка поехала, под  спиннером образовалось свободное место. Тогда возник вопрос в правильности, как бы это сделать по уму. Конечно можно опять поиграться с `android:layout_weight`, но думаю это не панацея.

Comment: Именно декларативно надо, программно не вариант?

Comment: Странно, раньше я так делал, но спиннер вообще пропадал... Возможно тогда дело было в AIDE, когда я мучал ее на работе. Спасибо. Забыл как преобразовать комментарий в ответ. Хмм, это только свой можно...

Comment: не понятно зачем оборачивать спиннер в леяут...

Comment: @metalurgus, да, точно. Раньше справа от него была кнопка. Потом в процессе эволюции я удалил ее, а лэйаут остался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить android:layout_weight="9" у лэйаута со спиннером. И поставить android:layout_height в wrap_content